# Lossless JPEG crop GUI for Linux

Tags: linux, image-processing, image-editor, jpg, lossless

I need a tool to crop pictures:

- Allows me to select a zone (graphical user interface).
- Crops JPEG files without any loss of quality. This means that it only allows me to select a zone at particular points ([iMCU boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_editing)).
- When selecting the zone, show the real place at which it will crop (typically a few pixels off the place where my mouse is).
- Gratis, ideally open source.
- Works on Linux, callable via right-click on JPEG file from Nautilus
- Very fast to start, even when called for the first time since rebooting my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CropGUI](https://github.com/jepler/cropgui) can do that.

Strong points:

- Extremely fast to start.
- Does the lossless crop.
- Open source (GPLv2).

Weak points:

- It is a bit bothersome to install (clone from Github and install the dependencies manually).
- The user interface is very rough. For instance, it does not tell you that it has saved the file nor where. So, you'll have to check the README and practice for 2 minutes before you can get fully productive.
- Two executables are included, cropgtk.py does not show you the final zone, but the older cropgui.py does.

[image: Screenshot of CropGTK]